# Magento CE 1.9.1.0 discount code on default one page checkout

Tags: onepage-checkout

I was originally using a custom theme for our Magento CE 1.9.1.0 however we decided to switch to use the default theme/pages for the checkout process. However I noticed that the discount code input box is not visible on the one page checkout?

I added the below code to the payment.phtml page. However our issue is when a user types in a coupon code and clicks apply they are redirected to the view cart page where they are presented with the success message.

```
  <?php 
      echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml')->toHtml(); 
  ?>
```

I am wondering how to make it so that the user will not be re-directed to the view cart page and instead stay on the checkout page to have the discount code applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as you did currently. you will need to do a code to make it work with onepage checkout process.

You can use this free extension for your requirement.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-coupon-code-from-your-checkout-process.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-discount-coupon-with-checkout-process-1.html

Comment: thank you. I used the first plugin listed and it works great